# WEKA ROC CURVE - colour interpretations

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, data-mining, roc

When we generate ROC curves from Weka, curve is displayed in a color scale. I understand what is a ROC curve. But what is the meaning of the color scale in this ROC curve?

[image]

Comment: It's the class... Just like it says!

Comment: yes I can see that. What I am asking is what does that imply? As I know different points in curve are pairs of (false positive rate, true positive rate)for different threshhold values. Is not it? so y color code this curve according to a class code? what does that mean?

Comment: does it represent the threshold values?

Comment: @Campino - no, it is not "a class" in any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Color depends on what have you **chosen**. In your case, you chosen **Colour: Threshold**, so the color represents threshold value set to get this pair of true FPR/TPR point.

In other words - ROC is a parametric curve of the threshold, so point (`tpr`, `fpr`) belongs to ROC if and only if there exists threshold value `t` for which experiment results in True positive rate=`tpr` and False positive rate=`fpr`. However, it is just an existance, so ROC as such does not show what is the exact value of `t` used. Coloring the curve gives you this one missing information.

Comment: Thank you for ur perfect answer :) I perfectly understood :)